# ASP.NET pages lag intermittently

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, iis

I'm using IIS 10, SQL Server 14, and .NET 4.5. I have made a website with just 4 pages of significance. Any one of them loads perfectly, every time. And quickly, even though they do a lot of work with datatables and database edits.

But if I open two browser windows (same session if it matters) and play around for a while loading pages in one window while the other is refreshing another of the pages every 3 seconds, it is only a matter of time until they freeze up for a bit. Sometimes only for 5 or 10 seconds. Often for over a minute, and sometimes for as long as 20 minutes.

What I've tried:

My first thought was SQL deadlock and I spent a long time down that rabbit hole. All my select statements now use `WITH (NOLOCK)`. I've run SQL profiler, and there is no discernible rhyme or reason to which queries have long durations during these periods, and none are that long. The longest "StartTime - EndTime" on the trace is never more than 0.25 seconds. I added my own StopWatch control to my functions that do my `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` statements and another on the one that gets my datatables, and see the same thing: max elapsed times during the hangs of 250ms or thereabouts. Under "normal" lag/hang-free operation, the elapsed times typically record 0ms, and at most maybe 3ms. The jump of 100x during the hang is confusing and concerning, but don't at all account for the long periods of lag/hang. And each time this happens, it will only be 1 or 2 statements with that extended duration.

I turned my attention to debugging the page that refreshes every 3 seconds. I use a StopWatch there also, and the page always loads in under 3ms as measured from the first line of the `form_load` event to the last line of the `form_unload` event. What is interesting here, is that while it is hung, it sure LOOKS LIKE Chrome (my browser) is trying to load the page. The little circle is spinning, and it is just waiting. It never times out, even if it takes 20 minutes. But during that time it will never record the first debug entry of `form_load`. Once it finally resolves, it will run the page as well as ever. So in my log I'll see something like this (oldest entry at the bottom):

```
2021-02-07 11:52:21.703 unload    
2021-02-07 11:52:21.700 load    
2021-02-07 11:52:18.642 unload    
2021-02-07 11:52:18.640 load    
2021-02-07 11:50:37.820 unload    
2021-02-07 11:50:37.817 load    
2021-02-07 11:50:34.777 unload    
2021-02-07 11:50:34.773 load
```

Note how the page loads quickly every time, and while there is normally a 3 second gap between loads, in one case there was almost a 2 minute gap.

Looking at my W3SVC1 logs, and lining it up to that same time, I see that there are entries (both POST and GET) for the pages with time-taken of around 90000 (not sure what units on that) where the entries before and after the problem are mostly in the 10-50 range.

I'm at a loss of what to look at next.

Comment: FYI: Deadlocks resolve quickly as SQL Server can detect them and kill one process. And I advise removing `nolock` as you don't want to use that unless you really have to and it certainly won't be the issue here.

Comment: In the W3C logs the time-taken field is measured in milliseconds.

Comment: I think this may be a problem in your code, I suggest you use breakpoints to debug in VS to see which piece of code is causing this problem.